# Using and implementing prefixes with ros2-control

Tags: ros2, ros2-control

in the launch files of the ros2_control examples it says

```py
    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "prefix",
            default_value='""',
            description="Prefix of the joint names, useful for \
        multi-robot setup. If changed than also joint names in the controllers' configuration \
        have to be updated.",
        )
    )
```

Therefore, using the prefix "axis_" and following the examples I tried to change variable names in my joint trajectory controller in the following manner

from

```
joint_trajectory_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - joint1
```

to

```
joint_trajectory_position_controller:
  ros__parameters:
    joints:
      - axis_joint1
```

However i still get this error and it doesnt work:

```
[ros2_control_node-1] terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
[ros2_control_node-1]   what():  Wrong state or command interface configuration.
[ros2_control_node-1] missing state interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-1] ' axis_joint1/position '  
[ros2_control_node-1] missing command interfaces:
[ros2_control_node-1] ' axis_joint1/position '
```

What else needs to be changed for this to work? I would appreciate any help, and I think it would be great if an example with a working prefix change could be added to the ros2_control examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out ALL occurrences of the joint name need to be replaced, especially(!!) the one in the urdf ros2_control node, which assigns the joint name to the hardware interface.